# Swing animation lag, SwingWorker not helping?

Tags: java, swing, animation, awt, worker-thread

I am drawing a simple animation, `Explosion` I have been trying to use a swing worker thread to do all of the "heavy computation"; however, my animation is still extremely slow, does this use below look correct for swingworker? or is the problem probably in my Animation class?

thanks!

```
JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setSize(new Dimension(800, 800));
    f.setVisible(true);
    Explosion e = new Explosion(400,400, 800,800);
    f.add(e);

    Timer t = new Timer(10, e2 -> {     
        SwingWorker w = new SwingWorker()
                {
                @Override
                protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
                    e.explode();
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void done()
                {
                    f.repaint();
                }
    };
    w.execute();

    });

    t.start();
```

Comment: Okay, so, every 10 seconds, you're calling your `SwingWorker`, which does "some" work, and when it complete's it repaints the UI.  Without knowing what `Explosion` does, I'm just going to say, there's a lot to question about your work flow. Consider providing a [mcve]

Comment: *does this use below look correct for swingworker?* - I would suggest you don't use a Timer to keep creating a new SwingWorker. Instead you start a single Swing worker. You then create an animation loop in the doInBackground() method and use Thread.sleep(...) to pause the loop. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Tasks That Have Interim Results](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/interim.html) for an example that might help.